# Windows service popping calc in C# Error 216 0xd8

Tags: windows, service

I coded this simple service -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MySimpleService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe";
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            p.StartInfo = psi;
            p.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And when I installed it with `sc.exe create test_service bitPath="<my_path>.exe"`,
I got an error message `Error 216 0xd8`.
I compiled the program on the same computer I ran the service on, any thoughts?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Also, Windows services do not have the rights to launch UI programs on the user's desktop, if that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: The exact message is Error 216 0xd8

Comment: It appears to be a bit-ness incompatibility among modules, which seems a bit odd in this context. Do you get this in response to the `sc` command, or only when you attempt to start the service?

Comment: only when i start the service

Comment: Are you perhaps compiling this as a 32-bit service and running it on a 64-bit box, or vice versa?